# Textarea Content Add Special characters

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, textarea

All I trying to add the custom javascript function in the textarea field and saving it to database in wordpress. Even output also works perfect but i getting the console error looks like
[image]

I added the javascript code in textarea looks like this way.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
jQuery('#notification-bar').show('slow');
});
```

While i saving it appears like

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
jQuery(\'#notification-bar\').show(\'slow\');
});
```

Why this should happen adding special characters to the textarea? Is there is a way to prevent those special characters append to the textarea instead of removing those special characters added in the content.

Any suggestion would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For security reason Wordpress doesn't allow special chars in the user inputs to avoid XSS attacks.